# Send '<%# Eval(“item”) %>' in email in ASP.Net using VB Code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a question about a new recorder on the site wants to enroll in a particular course who shall by clicking on the registration link .. Then enter the data via the registration code .. OK .. and then send the data to email The code works correctly .. but my question here .. How do I bring this session data for email? How I Can Send Eval(“item”) for new user who regist to Email Like :
Course Name
Days ...

Code as follows:

Schedule.aspx :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCourse" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 30%;">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelEnglishName" runat="server" CssClass="LabelReg"><%# Eval("EnglishName")%></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <label id="CityCountry" style="float: left; margin-left: -15px; margin-right: 15px; color: maroon; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; width: 20%; margin-top: 20px;"><%# Eval("CityCountry")%></label>
        <label id="StartCourse" style="float: left; color: maroon; font-size: 13px; width: 20%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: -13px; margin-top: 20px;"><%# Eval("StartCourse", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")%></label>
        <label id="EndCourse" style="float: left; color: maroon; font-size: 13px; width: 20%; margin-top: 20px;"><%# Eval("EndCourse", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")%></label>
        <label id="Days" style="float: left; width: 20%; margin-top: 20px;"><%# Eval("Days")%></label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

VB.Net Code

```html
Public Function FindCourse() As DataTable
        GetConnection()
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT ScheduleNew.ScheduleID, ScheduleNew.CourseID , ScheduleNew.CityID, ScheduleNew.StartCourse, ScheduleNew.EndCourse, ScheduleNew.Days, ScheduleNew.CountryID, ScheduleNew.CategoryID, ScheduleNew.FieldID , ScheduleNew.Note, ScheduleNew.MonthsID , CoursesNew.CourseLogo , CoursesNew.EnglishName , (City.CityName +', '  +Country.CountryName) AS CityCountry  FROM ScheduleNew ,CoursesNew , Country , City , Months  Where Country.CountryID=City.CountryID AND City.CityID=ScheduleNew.CityID AND CoursesNew.CourseID=ScheduleNew.CourseID AND Months.MonthsID = ScheduleNew.MonthsID "
 
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn)
 
        If CountryID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = " AND City.CountryID = @CountryID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CountryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CountryID
        End If
 
        If ScheduleID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= "And ScheduleNew.ScheduleID =@ScheduleID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ScheduleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ScheduleID
        End If
 
        If CourseID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= "And ScheduleNew.CourseID =@CourseID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CourseID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CourseID
        End If
 
        If CityID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.CityID =@CityID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CityID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CityID
        End If
 
        If StartCourse <> "" Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.StartCourse Like @StartCourse "
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartCourse", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "%" & StartCourse & "%"
        End If
 
        If EndCourse <> "" Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.EndCourse Like @EndCourse"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndCourse", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "%" & EndCourse & "%"
        End If
 
        If MonthsID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.MonthsID=@MonthsID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@MonthsID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MonthsID
        End If
 
        If CategoryID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.CategoryID=@CategoryID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CategoryID
        End If
 
        If FieldID <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.FieldID=@FieldID"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FieldID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FieldID
        End If
 
        If Days <> 0 Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " And ScheduleNew.Days=@Days"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Days", SqlDbType.int).Value = Days
        End If
 
 
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " order by StartCourse asc"
 
        Try
            da.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error
        Finally
            Conn.Close()
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
```

Images Of Pages :

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4539/spzkruw8_png.htm

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4539/dvndgvpy_png.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `OnItemCommand` event for that. Add the event to the Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCourse" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterCourse_ItemCommand">
```

And add a button to the Repeater template with a `CommandName` and a `CommandArgument`.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandName="emailCourse" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("item") %>' />
```

And then in code behind.

```
Protected Sub RepeaterCourse_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    'check if the commandname is the correct one (multiple buttons can use the same itemcommand)
    If (e.CommandName = "emailCourse") Then
        'get the value of the commandargument
        Dim itemID As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString

        'send the email here
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD,

OK , I will execute this code .

Thank You Very Much .